# Underscore.js is not working with MVC Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, underscore.js

I have added **underscore.js** reference in **BundleConfig.cs** for my MVC project, and the corresponding Bundle in **_Layout.cshtml** like however I am doing for all other JavaScript files.

But, I am getting JavaScript syntax error when using like below:

```
_.bindAll(ds,'save','del');
```

Can anybody please tell what I'm missing.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: red wavy lines under the above line of code.